# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: java, android

I don't even know where to start or even how to ask.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
```

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> > java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (no error message)

```
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1.241 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I've never updated Android Studio, and I saw some similar problems and non of the solutions they gave worked for me.

I tried to change the class path from

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

    }
```

to

```
 dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.3'

    }
```

I don't know where to go from there

Comment: You should put the dependency back to 1.5.0. What happens if you do the other suggestion in that post and do Build > Rebuild Project?

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan Same error